# Jquery toggling a div animate and same time a class name change

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

Thanks for attention firstly,
i use jquery for this aim `when i click a $('.icon') it must be do two thing first animate $('.thediv') to a {top: of '90px and back 0px'}, and the second thing changeing the $('.icon') class for gaining a chevron-up and back to chevron-down,
i dont understand what i am doing right;
 here is the fiddle

```js
var fltro = function(){
 var t = 200;
 $('.filter-tog .fa').click(function(){
  $('.filter').animate({top: '70px'}, t);
  $('.filter-tog .fa').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
 });
  $('.filter-tog .fa').click(function(){
  $('.filter').animate({top: '20px'}, t);
  $('.filter-tog .fa').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
 });
};
$(document).ready(fltro);
```

```css
.header{
  height:50px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
}
.filter{
 width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(16, 160, 122);
    z-index: -4;
}
.filter-tog{
  width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(27, 77, 88);
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 308px;
    z-index: 8;
}
.filter-tog i{
 line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="filter-tog">
 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="filter">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the fiddle.

Comment: I had flagged this post before it was edited

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable to keep track of the state of the toggle condition:

```
var t = 200, st = 0;
$('.filter-tog .fa').click(function() {
    if (st==0){
        $('.filter').animate({
            top: '70px'
        }, t);
        $('.filter-tog .fa').switchClass('fa-chevron-down', 'fa-chevron-up');
        st++;
    }else{
        $('.filter').animate({
            top: '20px'
        }, t);
        $('.filter-tog .fa').switchClass('fa-chevron-up', 'fa-chevron-down');
        st = 0;
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2rLsv7dd/15/)</kbd>

Comment: But i think it will only work for the first click, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Hey asker I took a little time to help and explain and refactor you code a little bit. This will help achieve the effect that you are looking for with out having to add anymore libraries such as jQuery UI

https://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/jocqqqb5/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $button = $('.filter-tog'); // find the button for clicking
   var $buttonIcon = $button.find('i'); // find the arrow for changing
   var $filter = $('.filter'); // find the filter so we can animate

   // Create a function to change the Icon
   var changeArrow = function () {
      $buttonIcon.toggleClass('fa-chevron-down').toggleClass('fa-  chevron-up')
   }

   // Create a function to add animate class use css 
   var animate = function(){
      $filter.toggleClass('animate');
   }

   // Anytime the button is clicked run the arrow and animate functions;
   $button.on('click',function(){
      changeArrow();
      animate();
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.filter {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(16, 160, 122);
  z-index: -4;
  /* Use the transition property so anytime the
  top position is changed the animation will be applied */
  transition: top 1s; 
}

.animate {
   top: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help i get the idea. Thank you very much.